# DSC: Applying one config to various operating systems

Tags: powershell, dsc

This problem has occurred during learning, so I am not sure how likely it is in the real world, but I am still interested to know the best way to handle this sort of thing.

I have the following composite configuration:

```
configuration hDefaultServer {
    Param 
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$myFileName,

        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateSet("Present","Absent")]
        [String]$Ensure = "Present"
    )

    WindowsFeature 'InstallGUI'
    {
        Ensure = $Ensure
        Name = 'Server-Gui-Shell'
    }
    File 'Temp'
    {
        Type = 'Directory'
        DestinationPath = "$($env:SystemDrive)\Temp"
        Ensure = $Ensure
    }
    File 'SomeFile'
    {
        Type = 'File'
        DestinationPath = "$($env:SystemDrive)\Temp\$myFileName"
        Contents = 'This file was created by DSC!'
        Ensure = $Ensure
    }    
}
```

And compile it into its .MOF with:

```
$ConfigData = @{
   AllNodes = @(
      @{ NodeName = "*"; PsDscAllowPlainTextPassword = $true },
      @{ NodeName = 'WMF5-1' }
   )
}


    Configuration DemoDefaultServer 
    {
        Param 
        (
            [string]$FileName
        )

        Import-DscResource -Name hDefaultServer

        hDefaultServer Demo2
        {
            myFileName = $FileName
            Ensure = "Present"
        }
    }

    DemoDefaultserver -ConfigurationData $ConfigData -OutputPath C:\Configurations\DemoDefaultServer -filename "SomeOtherFile.txt"
```

When I run it on a Windows 10 box, it completes the file and folder stuff, but errors as ServerManager doesn't exist on Windows 10 client:

```
PowerShell DSC resource MSFT_RoleResource  failed to execute Test-TargetResource functionality with error message: Installing roles and features using PowerShell Desired State Configuration is supported only on Server 
SKU's. It is not supported on Client SKU.
```

Which is fair enough. What is the best way to handle a case like this?

If I do something like this:

```
configuration hDefaultServer {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param 
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$myFileName,

        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateSet("Present","Absent")]
        [String]$Ensure = "Present"
    )

    $ProductType = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).ProductType

    If($ProductType -eq 1)
    {
        Write-Verbose "Client OS ($ProductType)"
    }
    elseif($ProductType -eq 2)
    {
        Write-Verbose "Domain Controller ($ProductType)"

        WindowsFeature 'InstallGUI'
        {
            Ensure = $Ensure
            Name = 'Server-Gui-Shell'
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Verbose "Server OS ($ProductType)"

        WindowsFeature 'InstallGUI'
        {
            Ensure = $Ensure
            Name = 'Server-Gui-Shell'
        }
    }
    File 'Temp'
    {
        Type = 'Directory'
        DestinationPath = "$($env:SystemDrive)\Temp"
        Ensure = $Ensure
    }
    File 'SomeFile'
    {
        Type = 'File'
        DestinationPath = "$($env:SystemDrive)\Temp\$myFileName"
        Contents = 'This file was created by DSC!'
        Ensure = $Ensure
    }    
}
```

At compile time, the .MOF file is adjusted accordingly. i.e. the InstallGUI section is added or removed.

There is also DependsOn, but from reading, I believe this is to define the order of application within the scope of a configuration. I haven't worked out the pattern on how this works, but for instance, I wanted to make sure the folder was created before the file, I could do (and just to prove it, I've changed the order so the file is listed before the folder):

```
configuration hDefaultServer {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param 
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$myFileName,

        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateSet("Present","Absent")]
        [String]$Ensure = "Present"
    )

    $ProductType = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).ProductType

    If($ProductType -eq 1)
    {
        Write-Verbose "Client OS ($ProductType)"
    }
    elseif($ProductType -eq 2)
    {
        Write-Verbose "Domain Controller ($ProductType)"

        WindowsFeature 'InstallGUI'
        {
            Ensure = $Ensure
            Name = 'Server-Gui-Shell'
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Verbose "Server OS ($ProductType)"

        WindowsFeature 'InstallGUI'
        {
            Ensure = $Ensure
            Name = 'Server-Gui-Shell'
        }
    }
    File 'SomeFile'
    {
        Type = 'File'
        DestinationPath = "$($env:SystemDrive)\Temp\$myFileName"
        Contents = 'This file was created by DSC!'
        Ensure = $Ensure
        DependsOn = "[File]Temp"
    }
    File 'Temp'
    {
        Type = 'Directory'
        DestinationPath = "$($env:SystemDrive)\Temp"
        Ensure = $Ensure
    }   
}
```

Is there a way with Try / Catch? Similar to the if statement. I did try it, but the .MOF contained the InstallGUI section.

I believe there's probably a better way using ConfigurationData. Something like:

```
$configData{
    AllNodes = @(
        @{
            NodeName = "WIN-AQEKG7L9SE8"
            Role = "Setup, WindowsFeatures, IE, SqlServer"
         }
    (
}
```

But I haven't worked this bit out yet. All the examples I have found, using this, seem to use "Role", that I believe is part of ServerManager and therefore not available on Windows 10.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a good idea to create TWO different DSCs.
It makes no sense to do this type of check.

A DSC is used for mass configuration. Configure 10 web servers, configure 10 sql servers, etc.